# Why child absolute positioned element cuts off when its parent element is animated using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a sidebar nav which collapses and expands on click of its child arrow icon element. The sidebar nav collapses to icons (I am not adding icons for this question) and expands to show nav text.

The functionality is working pretty good except one issue. When the arrow icon (white circle) is clicked to show/hide the nave, it cuts off and returns to its original shape until the nav attains its final width. I tried various solutions but none worked. But if I remove position absolute of #header_arrow, then this cut off issue sorts out but I must need this css to put the icon at right position.

Please see the code/demo below and help me to fix it.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
  // arrow button to collapse side nav
  $('#header_arrow').click(function(){
   if($('#header_nav').hasClass('header_showing')) { // if nav is showing links
    $('.header_nav_text').hide();
    $('#header_nav').animate({width:'50px'},1200);
    $('#cont').animate({'margin-left':'50px'},1200);
    $('#header_nav').removeClass('header_showing').addClass('header_hidden');
   } else if($('#header_nav').hasClass('header_hidden')) { // if nav has hidden links
    $('.header_nav_text').show();
    $('#header_nav').animate({width:'200px'},1200);
    $('#cont').animate({'margin-left':'200px'},1200);
    $('#header_nav').removeClass('header_hidden').addClass('header_showing');
   }
  });
    });
```

```css
 /* nav */
 .header_showing {width:200px;}
 .header_hidden {width:50px;}
 .header_hidden .header_nav_text {display:none;}
 .header_showing #header_nav_notifications_no {margin-left:4px;}
 .header_hidden #header_nav_notifications_no {margin-left:-10px;}
 #header_nav {background:#2c3b4d; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #2c3b4d; color:#fff; height:40px; left:0; position:fixed; top:0; height:100%; padding-top:20px; z-index:10;}
 #header_arrow {background:url(../images/header-arrow.png) no-repeat center center #fff; background-size:5px 10px; border:1px solid #2c3b4d; border-radius:50%; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #2c3b4d; color:#2c3b4d; cursor:pointer; height:26px; line-height:26px; position:absolute; right:-13px; text-align:center; top:20px; width:26px; z-index:11;}
 #header_nav li {}
 #header_nav li a {background-size:15px 15px; background-position:left center; display:block; height:40px; line-height:40px; margin-left:15px; padding:0 0 0 25px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="header_nav" class="header_showing">
        <div id="header_arrow" class="header_nav_hide">&nbsp;</div>
        <li><a id="header_prospects" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Prospects</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="header_customers" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Customers</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="header_notifications" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Notifications</span><span id="header_nav_notifications_no">0</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="header_tasks" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Tasks</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="header_reports" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Reports</span></a></li>
        <li id="header_logout_cont"><a id="header_logout" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Log Out</span></a></li>
        <li id="header_settings_cont"><a id="header_settings" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Settings</span></a></li>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Because animation adds `overflow: hidden`. Use DevTools to see inline CSS of animation

Comment: @Justinas yes, i know during animation overflow hidden is applied to sidenav bar, but is it causing this issue? If so, then how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix is to set `overflow: visible !important;` in your header_nav

```
#header_nav {
background:#2c3b4d; 
overflow: visible !important; 
box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #2c3b4d; 
color:#fff; 
height:40px; 
left:0; 
position:fixed; 
top:0; 
height:100%; 
padding-top:20px; 
z-index:10;
}
```

**EDIT**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // arrow button to collapse side nav
  $('#header_arrow').click(function(){
   if($('#header_nav').hasClass('header_showing')) { // if nav is showing links
    $('.header_nav_text').hide();
    $('#header_nav').animate({width:'50px'},1200).css('overflow','visible');
    $('#cont').animate({'margin-left':'50px'},1200);
    $('#header_nav').removeClass('header_showing').addClass('header_hidden');
   } else if($('#header_nav').hasClass('header_hidden')) { // if nav has hidden links
    $('.header_nav_text').show();
    $('#header_nav').animate({width:'200px'},1200).css('overflow','visible');
    $('#cont').animate({'margin-left':'200px'},1200);
        
    $('#header_nav').removeClass('header_hidden').addClass('header_showing');
   }
  });
    });
```

```css
/* nav */
 .header_showing {width:200px;}
 .header_hidden {width:50px;}
 .header_hidden .header_nav_text {display:none;}
 .header_showing #header_nav_notifications_no {margin-left:4px;}
 .header_hidden #header_nav_notifications_no {margin-left:-10px;}
 #header_nav {background:#2c3b4d; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #2c3b4d; color:#fff; height:40px; left:0; position:fixed; top:0; height:100%; padding-top:20px; z-index:10;}
 #header_arrow {background:url(../images/header-arrow.png) no-repeat center center #fff; background-size:5px 10px; border:1px solid #2c3b4d; border-radius:50%; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #2c3b4d; color:#2c3b4d; cursor:pointer; height:26px; line-height:26px; position:absolute; right:-13px; text-align:center; top:20px; width:26px; z-index:11;}
 #header_nav li {}
 #header_nav li a {background-size:15px 15px; background-position:left center; display:block; height:40px; line-height:40px; margin-left:15px; padding:0 0 0 25px;}
.small-container{ overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="header_nav" class="header_showing">
        <div id="header_arrow" class="header_nav_hide">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="small-container">
        <li><a id="header_prospects" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Prospects</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="header_customers" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Customers</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="header_notifications" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Notifications</span><span id="header_nav_notifications_no">0</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="header_tasks" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Tasks</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="header_reports" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Reports</span></a></li>
        <li id="header_logout_cont"><a id="header_logout" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Log Out</span></a></li>
        <li id="header_settings_cont"><a id="header_settings" class="anim_btn" href="#"><span class="header_nav_text">Settings</span></a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </ul>
```

You were right, this was a dirty solution.

I came up with a workaround without `!important`

```
$('#header_nav').animate({width:'50px'},1200).css('overflow','visible');
```

For the expanding problem, I used a helper-container `<div class="small-container">`, which has `overflow:hidden`, so the words can't break out

Comment: No, that is not a proper solution. Though it does work but what happens when sidenav bar changes from collapse to expand. The nav text starts appearing even before full sidenav is shown which looks really very ugly.

Comment: @user5307298 you were right, this was a very dirty solution - have a look at my edits - it should fit your needs now

Comment: yes I looked at your edits. Your solution is now perfect! Thanks.